# Define and use a “variable” in a Target

Tags: msbuild

In a `Target`, I need to use `%(Foo.Filename)%(Foo.Extension)` several times.

Is there a way to define a “variable” (or something similar) that can be used instead of `%(Foo.Filename)%(Foo.Extension)`? Preferably inside the `Target`?

(For the sake of completeness: `%(Foo.Identity)` is something different.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on how the `%` is being used in that target, as it's not just a shorthand to reference metadata as if it's a class property but a method of batching item groups. Sans some edge cases, e.g. item group of 1, [creating a property during execution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171458) won't work as it'll overwrite itself on loop; most common way would be to either do [target batching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228229.aspx), [transforms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms171476.aspx) or custom [metadata](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms171453.aspx#BKMK_ItemMetadata).

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup>
    <Foo Include="*.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="Foo">
    <ItemGroup>
      <Foo>
        <Lorem>Ipsum.%(Filename)%(Extension)</Lorem>
      </Foo>
    </ItemGroup>
    <Message Text="%(Foo.Lorem)" />
  </Target>

  <Target Name="Bar">
    <ItemGroup>
      <Lorem Include="Ipsum.%(Foo.Filename)%(Extension)" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Message Text="@(Lorem)" />
    <Message Text="@(Foo -> 'Ipsum.%(Filename)%(Extension)')" />
  </Target>

  <Target Name="Baz" Inputs="@(Foo)" Outputs="Ipsum.%(Filename)%(Extension)">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <Lorem>Ipsum.%(Foo.Filename)%(Extension)</Lorem>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Message Text="$(Lorem)" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Comment: This really is a comprehensive answer. Thanks!